# DE-9 Connector for 100BaseTX Ethernet - How to assign pinout?

Tags: connector, ethernet, pinout

I need to use a DE-9 connector for my Ethernet Interface (RGMII 100Base-TX) which has two pairs of differential signals TX and RX. I have attached the pinout for the DE-9 connector below.
[image: DB9 Connector]

I have the freedom of assigning the pinout as I see fit. Essentially we will have TX+, TX-, RX+, RX- and GND and Shields.

Does anyone have a recommendation on what the best pinout would be?

Comment: There is no RGMII there. RGMII is between the MAC and the PHY. You're using the DB9 in place of the RJ-45, right? Is this a capacitively coupled link side of the PHY, or are you using magnetics?

Comment: The proper name for that connector is and has always been DE-9. (DB-9 is an incorrect term that came about lately.) See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-subminiature#Description,_nomenclature,_and_variants

Comment: @Kuba - Hi, Do you want me to edit your comment above to change "DB9" to "DE-9" as in your answer? (Or you could repost your comment with the correction - I just thought I would offer to save you the time :) )

Comment: I was going to post an answer referencing full duplex rs485 DE-9 standards but a quick survey indicates everyone does something different, and there's no easy to find cable assemblies anyways. Time to be a trailblazer!

Comment: Why there is both shield and GND? Ethernet is an isolated interface. If you just used standard 8P8C connector, at most the connector metal shell would connect to CAT cable shield. How you would connect the metal shell to ground or if at all is then another thing. Also using a connector for Ethernet that is used commonly for other things as well has some risks. Someone might come and plug any other device there that fits.

Comment: @Justme, so would I need to carry grounds through some of these pins or just keep them as a no connect?

Comment: @Matty I don't know what you should do, as a standard Ethernet sockect connects to 8 data pins and shield of the cable. But you have only 4 data wires, and the shield. And it is unclear what you mean by ground and which ground and what would do with that on the connector, as the point of Ethernet is to be an isolated interface.

Answer (score 3):

You might be better served by using one of the multitude of industrial shielded connectors designed for Ethernet. An M12 connector would be the usual choice, and then you can use standard industrial sensor cables. They include shielding, come in various lengths, and are usually yellow instead of gray or beige. This improves workplace morale, per my experience.

DE-9 is just such an oddball choice here, and unnecessary. And you'll usually find that making your own cables for common interfaces is a waste of money: you can't compete with companies that churn those out by the tens of thousands. They'll usually have better QC too.

But if you insist on DE-9, and I advise against it, then the pinout doesn't matter all that much. You should keep the pairs on adjacent pins, straddling the two rows, and that's about it.

Comment: I suppose the most... familiar? thing one could do, is take for example a common RS-422 or -485 pinout using DE-9, and use whatever pairs for RX/TX. Possibly, cables are available (with proper twisted pairs) this way?

Comment: You may want to consider what would happen if someone tried to apply PoE through that setup and accidentally plugged it into a device expecting a standard RS232/422/485 pinout and try to minimize the resulting damage.

Comment: @TimWilliams Someone might connect a RS232/RS422/RS485 device to this Ethernet DE9 and blow the Ethernet magnetics. vir Thankfully PoE autodetects if device supports PoE. Unless passive PoE is used which is terrible.

Comment: You never know sometimes.  We have to work with a device that implemented PoE incorrectly and blows up anything connected to its RF terminals.